# IBM Watson Knowledge Studio how to deploy a model in trial version?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, watson-knowledge-studio

I am trying to create a free model in watson knowledge studio but When I take a snapshot from my model of current version, I am taking an error like "only 1 model permitted in free plan".

According to the ibm's explanation that we can create one model and deploy to a trial version of Natural Language Understanding. What is my mistake ? How can I solve this problem ? Thank you for helping!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYO79.png)

Comment: Are you experiencing error on creating snapshot on WKS?
I believe you can create multiple version of snapshot.
The limitation of "only 1 model permitted in free plan" is expected to be happen on deploying your model to Trial NLU instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple snapshots in Watson Knowledge Studio (WKS), but in the free account, we can deploy only one snapshot at a time to either NLU or Discovery.

If you want to deploy a new model to NLU, first you'll have to un-deploy the old one using the WKS interface and then deploy the new one.